# Excel custom time format with optional hours

Tags: excel, time, custom-formatting

I have a range of data which are in a time format of hh:mm.ss (my original dataset is imported through a csv this way). I need to transform it to a correct format (hh:mm:ss) to make calculations and that's easily done using the replace functionality.

The issue is that some of these data don't have the hh part, they are just mm.ss, so when I replace "." with ":" they become hh:mm instead of mm:ss, e.g. 06m.30s becomes 06h:30m.

Does anyone know how to make a custom time format that will take as default value the mm and include the hh only when necessary?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You write that the format is `hh:mm.ss` or `mm.ss`, which, to me, implies `00:06.30` or `06.30`. But then you given an example of `06m.30s`.  Which is it?  Actually, it would be best if you provide an example of the raw `csv` file (as seen in Notepad).  And also which version of Excel you are using.

Comment: I put the "m" and "s" to help people understand the example, they are not included in the format. It is either hh:mm.ss or mm.ss as you stated. I use 2016 version. Unfortunately I cannot provide the csv file as it contains sensitive information

Comment: As far as I know, there is no custom format that will do what you want.  You may need to do the conversion during the import process.  Designating the column as Text, and then testing for how many colons `:` are present may allow you to convert the values appropriately.  Without an example demonstrating your problem, I would be guessing at solutions.  Surely you can create something.

Comment: When csv has mm.ss what wold you like the hour to be? You can not keep it blank

Comment: It could be "00", it's not of big importance. The important thing is for it to be able to perform correct calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that during the import process, the time column is imported as `TEXT`

**EDIT:** Formula shortened.

> Convert the values to a **REAL** Excel time

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERR(FIND(":",A2)),"00:"&A2,A2),".",":"))
```

or

```
=--(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERR(FIND(":",A2)),"00:"&A2,A2),".",":"))
```

> Apply your desired Time format to the result

```
hh:mm:ss
```

[image]